# Selenium 2 opens Google Chrome but doesn't load webpages

Tags: selenium2

When I execute a test calling google chrome (*googlechrome), Selenium Wedriver opens a browser and starts to launch the test cases but it doesn't load anything. I had the same problem with Firefox and IE but I solved it opening the proxy's/adding user sessions. I don't know if it's the same problem for Chrome or what's happening.

I work with Selenium grid 2, Jenkins and a Java interface. Paths for chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe are added in my environment (instances of *googlechrome appear in my grid2), in fact as I said Selenium Webdriver opens the browser but doesn't load, I have searched for a solution during days on the Internet but nothing...

Someone can help me? I have chromedriver and the references to it in my environment path.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you include the code you are using and any errors you might be getting?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, we just need to add `-Dhttp.proxyHost=isa.be.bvdep.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080` in the command line to launch the node.

Comment: Well done for finding your solution! To take the question off the Unanswered list, it's best to accept your own answer.